# Java class and WSDL files cannot connect to each other

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

At first, I placed the java class file together with the wsdl files inside the WEB-INF folder, they successfully connected. But when I moved the java class file and the wsdl files inside the scr folder because I need to call the java class inside the jsp file, something went wrong. The java class now is full of errors. Seems like they didn't connected. I already configured the wsdl file in web client service. I'm using eclipse as development tools.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Variables error. Variables that configured as well in WSDL.